# How can I find power series of $f(x)$?

Tags: functions, power-series, continued-fractions

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{x}{1+\dfrac{x^2}{1+\dfrac{x^3}{1+\dfrac{x^4}{\ddots}}}}}$$

How can a power series be found given the continued fraction $f(x)$?

I'm trying to find $f(x) =1+a_1x+\dfrac{a_2x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{a_3x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{a_4x^4}{4!}+\cdots$

I tried some ways to define $f(x)$ but I could not find the general patern. It goes to complex patern after $n=3$ in my approach. I think that I need another approach to problem.

$$\begin{align}
&f_1(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots\\
&f_2(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{1+x^2}}=\frac{1+x^2}{1+x+x^2}\\
&f_3(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{1+\frac{x^2}{1+x^3}}}=\frac{1+x^2+x^3}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4}\\
&\lim_{n\to \infty} {f_n(x)}=f(x)
\end{align}$$

Could you please give me hand on how to find the patern of this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the reciprocal of the classic [Rogers-Ramanujan Continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction). A listing of some of the power series coefficients can be found here: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003823). You might be able to find more references there.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How can I get the same result as Rogers-Ramanujan got. I try to learn the proof.

Comment: @Mathlover: I haven't really gone through the proofs myself, and I don't expect they will be easy. I suggest you follow the references. These will probably be covered in some number theory textbooks.

Comment: @Mathlover: you'll want to look at the "Ramanujan's Lost Notebooks" series published by Springer-Verlag; I forget which, but one of the volumes goes into excruciating detail (through a modular forms detour) to derive a series from the CF...